# How to find the occurrence of names in a file?

Tags: text-processing

I want to know how many times users who have logged on the system in a single command.

I have used repetitive commands to find the how many times he have logged.

```
$ last | grep -c user1
$ last | grep -c user2
```

Is there any alternative for the command in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$ last | grep -E -c 'user1|user2'
```

The `-E` allows to leave out the `\` character that you would otherwise need before the `|`.

If you have many user names listed in a file, one per line, you can read them from the file directly:

```
$ last | grep -F -c -f userlist.txt
```

The `-F` means the lines in the files are strings that should match as they are, not regular expressions.

Comment: Congrats BTW on getting to 3k!

Answer (score 0):

Use egrep instead of grep for extended functionality.

```
$ last | egrep "(user1|user2)"
```

If your output is long you can make it scroll-able for easy viewing with the "less" pager:

```
$ last | egrep "(user1|user2)" | less
```